# Cannot change colorscheme in leiningen ultra plugin settings

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I discovered leiningen ultra plugin, which provides a colorized REPL amongst other things: https://github.com/venantius/ultra

However, the colors, especially the "blue" for function symbols are not very readable in my terminal with the black background.
I'd like to change the colors but wasn't able to do this following the documentation.

I added following configuration to my`profiles.clj` right under the `:user` key, but nothing has changed

```
:ultra {:repl {:color-scheme {:function-symbol [:red]
                              :class-delimiter [:red]}}}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Has anyone been successful in setting custom color scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Following configuration in `~/lein/profiles.clj` works for me:

```clj
{:user {:plugins [[venantius/ultra "0.5.1"]]
        :ultra {:repl {:color-scheme {:delimiter [:blue]
                                      :symbol [:green]
                                      :keyword [:bold :yellow]}}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works for me as well.
However, for some reason, the function names are still in blue when I invoke `(source map)`

Comment: Image showing the result of `(source map)` in my terminal: http://imgur.com/hLyuFNt

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

It seems that it's not possible to provide custom colorscheme to modify output of `source`.
https://github.com/venantius/glow is used to colorize the output of source and the `terminal-default` colorscheme is hardcoded in ultra plugin: https://github.com/venantius/ultra/blob/7ccac0749220028cda4c3c1ab4d4d45503cce0cc/src/ultra/repl.clj#L21